# find hidden column value in a dynamacally bind html table with Sharepoint list - Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have following code. Now I want to get the hidden column value based on user selected row. I also want to highlight the entire row, not only the e.target.
Can someone please help me.

```
function getTermdetailsQuerySuccsess(sender, args) {

    var listEnumerator = Termsitems.getEnumerator();
    var datatable = document.getElementById("TermList");



    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {

        var oListItem = listEnumerator.get_current();

        //var firstName = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Title');
        //var secondName = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('LastName');
        var termID = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('ID');
        var startdate = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('startdate');
        var enddate = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Enddate');
        var termtype = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('TermType');
        var Hours = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Hours');
        var EdNone = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('EdNoned');
        var Specialty = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Specialty');

        var Subspecialty = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Subspecialty');
        var Hospital = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Hospital');
        var DEMT = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('DEMT');
        var Supervisor = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Supervisor');

        rowcount = rowcount + 1;
        $("#TermList").append("<tr style='border-bottom:1px silver solid' align='middle'  class='gradeA'>" +

                                  "<td align='left' style='display:none'>" + termID + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + startdate + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + enddate + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + termtype + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + Hours + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + EdNone + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + Specialty + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + Subspecialty + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + Hospital + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + DEMT + "</td>" +

                                  "<td align='left'>" + Supervisor + "</td>" +

                                  "</tr>");

    }

}

 $('#TermList').click(function (e) {
        var tr = $(e.target).parent().index() ;
        alert(tr);
        alert($(e.target).text()); // using jQuery
        //  var Cells = tr.e.getElementsByTagName("td");

        $(e.target).addClass('row-highlight');


        var confirmationM = confirm("Do you want to edit this term deatils ?");
        if (confirmationM == true) {
            confirmation = "You pressed OK!";
        }
        else {
            confirmation = "You pressed Cancel!";
            $(e.target).removeClass('row-highlight');
        }
    });


 $('#TermList').click(function (e) {
        var tr = $(e.target).parent().index() ;
        alert(tr);
        alert($(e.target).text()); // using jQuery
        //  var Cells = tr.e.getElementsByTagName("td");

        $(e.target).addClass('row-highlight');


        var table = $("#TermList")[0];
        var cell = table.rows[tr].cells[1];
        alert(cell);


        var confirmationM = confirm("Do you want to edit this term deatils ?");
        if (confirmationM == true) {
            confirmation = "You pressed OK!";
        }
        else {
            confirmation = "You pressed Cancel!";
            $(e.target).removeClass('row-highlight');
        }
    });
```

I have following code. Now I want to get the hidden column value based on user selected row. I also want to highlight the entire row, not only the e.target.
Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of ways to improve/optimize your code. For example, instead of calling `$(e.target)` each time, you should save it into a variable: `var $target = $(e.target)`, same thing for `listEnumerator.get_current()`, why do you call it all the time when you saved the value into `oListItem` ?!

But anyway, it's not your question.

Instead of binding the full table, you could bind only the TD: `$('#TermList').click(function (e) {` becomes `$('#TermList').on('td', 'click', function(e) {`

Then, to find the row, you just need to do:

```
var $td = $(this); // here it's your selected cell
var $tr = $td.parent(); // here it's your selected row
$tr.addClass('row-highlight'); // highlight the row
```

And to find the value in the first cell:

```
alert($tr.find('td:first').text()); // return the value of the first cell
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi AymKdn,

Thank you fro your help and advice.
I have tried to use $('#TermList').on('td', 'click', function(e) {, but this doesn't do anything, do I need to change the following part as well? if so could you please tell me how.
$("#TermList").append("<tr style='border-bottom:1px silver solid' align='middle'  class='gradeA'>" +

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you use the last version of jQuery ? (v9.x or 10.x) Also make sure Your HTML Table called "TermList" is created into the DOM *before* calling the binding function!